# Join arrays expression in ECMAScript 2016

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to JavaScript. I need to write simple script which should join several arrays into one. I found this example:

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

But I have more than two arrays.
Is it possible to concat several arrays in one expression?

Comment: yes, just try it..

Comment: do you know how many you want to concat ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I need to concat 4 arrays. @dpetrini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var arr3 = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
var arr4 = ['j', 'k', 'l'];

var arr5 = Array.prototype.concat.apply(arr1, [arr2, arr3, arr4]);
console.log(arr5);
```

By this means you can concat n number of arrays. Just add more arrays after arr4.

---

If you have array of arrays, Something like this,

```
 var arr1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

You can use spread,

```
var arr2 = Array.prototype.concat(...arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `[].concat(...arrs)` over `Array.prototype` - it's shorter and making the intention more clear

Comment: Btw, it's not called "destructuring", the three dots are *spread syntax*.

Comment: Array.prototype is faster than using [ ], but not by quite far. It good to use Array.prototype generic methods in critical codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply multiple arrays to `Array.prototype.concat` function.

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
var arr3 = [7, 8, 9];

arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);     //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Array method `concat()` returns the concatenation result which you can in turn use for your next concatenation.

If you have a static list of arrays (3 for example):

```
let result = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3);
```

If you have an array of arrays:

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bigArr.length; i++) {
    result = result.concat(bigArr[i]);
}
```